# Retinotopic mapping to higher visual cortex

Tags: neuroscience, vision

I know visual stimuli from retina presented in Cartesian coordinate is mapped to V1 as a form of polar coordinates. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinotopy), [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Visual_map)

But I wonder whether this spatial representation in polar coordinate in V1 is maintained to the higher visual cortex such as IT. I searched for some papers regarding this, but I could not find the paper showing clear picture of how visual stimuli is mapped to higher layer of visual cortex other than V1.

In case of Convolutional Neural Network (CNN), one of the types of Artificial Neural Network (ANN), input image to the CNN is in the Cartesian coordinate and this Cartesian coordinate is maintained to the last layer. In the similar context, I was wondering if the first layer of the visual cortex is in polar coordinate, whether this polar coordinate is maintained as this signal goes up to the higher layer of visual cortex.

Could you suggest me some materials related to this topic?

Comment: Have you checked out the following article yet? It has pictures of how visual stimuli is mapped to higher layer of visual cortex other than V1: Wandell BA, Dumoulin SO, Brewer AA. [Visual field maps in human cortex.](https://www.cell.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0896-6273%2807%2900774-X) Neuron. 2007 Oct 25;56(2):366-383.